# order by count(catid) without group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want count how many rows use the same catid and order the query by total.

```
id | catid | name
0  | 1     | foo
1  | 1     | bar
2  | 2     | paint
```

I've tried `COUNT(catid)` but this requires a `GROUP BY`, and I do not want to compress rows.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want window functions?

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by catid) as cat_cnt
from t
order by cat_cnt, catid;
```

I should note that if you don't want to see the total, you can put the window function in the `order by`:

```
select *
from t
order by count(*) over (partition by catid), catid
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could run the GROUP BY as a separate SELECT, then JOIN?

E.g.

```
select orig.*, summ.totals
from t
join (select count(cat_id) totals 
         from t 
         group by cat_id) summ
on t.cat_id = summ.cat_id;
```